# How to know which alert button user has touched for CLLocationManager?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

The `CLLocationManager` prompts an alert

> "App name" Would you like to use your location

which offers two buttons, **OK** and **Don't allow**. How to know which of the buttons has the user selected?

Comment: Why don't you check if you have access to the location of the user? If you do, he selected OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click on Don't allow button

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`
will be called with `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` exception. You can write your inside it.

Also refer :

```
kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0, // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,        // This application is not authorized to use location services.  Due
                                             // to active restrictions on location services, the user cannot change
                                             // this status, and may not have personally denied authorization
kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,            // User has explicitly denied authorization for this application, or
                                             // location services are disabled in Settings
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized         // User has authorized this application to use location services
```

Example :

if user clicks on allow then

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
      [self refreshYourView];
}
```

If clicks on don't allow

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if ([error code]== kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) 
    {
         UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"User has clicked don't allow button." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

     }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternate : you can display an alert that ask user to allow location access by enable location service from `Settings`.

You can use this on iOS 5.0 and later:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

in your app to open Settings app.

Comment: I am doing this two times in my application. Once in appdelegate and then in one of controllers where I have mapview. If user selects Ok in appdelegate CLLocationManager alert, application should not prompt this alert inside ma controller. But if user selects Don't allow in start, app should prompt this alert inside map controller. How to do this?

Comment: @Nitish: set a flag when user selects don't allow and check that flag into your map controller. If flag is false then ask user to allow it.

Comment: This isn't what I require. CLLocationManager should prompt same alert in map controller if user selected Don't allow in app start. And if user selected Ok in start, no alert should appear in map controller.

Comment: But alert is not coming. Location is visible/not visible depending on bool but alert is not being displayed.

Comment: @Nitish : I am not sure but I think its a system alert so it occurs only once when you install and run app first time.

Comment: I wouldn't advise using that code to open the settings app. As far as I know, it was deprecated just after iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 5):

Implement [CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)

locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:

Tells the delegate that the authorization status for the application changed.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

Parameters

manager

```
 The location manager object reporting the event.
```

status

```
The new authorization status for the application.
```

Discussion

This method is called whenever the application’s ability to use location services changes. **Changes can occur because the user allowed or denied the use of location services for your application or for the system as a whole**.